# Using AngularJS and ui.router with $StateChangeStart to deal with Session API at $rootScope level with logic flow

Tags: angularjs, session, angular-ui-router

What I am trying to do is verify user authentication and respond accordingly. Either populate the $rootScope with session data or redirect to the login page. I want the session data to be accessible to other controllers and views.

The Session response from the server is a JSON object:

```
{"user_id":"17","name":"Administrator","user_email":"admin@example.com"}
```

My app.js looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider){
        $stateProvider
            .state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                templateUrl: 'app/views/login.html'
            })
            .state('logout', {
                url:'/logout',
                templateUrl: 'app/views/login.html'
            })
            .state('dashboard', {
                url:'/dashboard',
                templateUrl:'app/views/dashboard.html',
                role: 0 
            });
        })
   .run(function($rootScope, $location, Data){
        $rootScope.$on('$StateChangeStart', function (event, toState,  fromState) {
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
            Data.get('session').then(function (results) { // Sends request to server the above mention JSON object is returned
            if (results.user_id) {
                $rootScope.authenticated = true;
                $rootScope.user_id = results.user_id;
                $rootScope.name = results.name;
                $rootScope.user_email = results.user_email;
            } else {
                $location.path("/login");
            }
        });
    });
```

Then in my controller:

```
app.controller('AuthCtrl', ['$scope','$rootScope', '$location', '$http', 'Data', function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, $http, Data) {
    $scope.login = {};
    $scope.doLogin = function (user) {
        Data.post('login', { // Sends login information to server               
            user: user
        }).then(function (results) {
            if (results.status == "success") {
                $location.path('dashboard');
            }
        });
    };  
    $scope.logout = function () {
        Data.get('logout').then(function (results) { // sends logout request to server
            $location.path('login');
        });
    }
}]);
```

The login function and response works as it should. The logout function works and destroys the session. The API on the server responds the way it should, but the session data is not stored or accessible in the $rootScope and I can not use it in my views.

The dashboard view looks like this:

```
<div ng-controller="AuthCtrl">
    <h4>User Authenticated</h4>
    User ID: {{user_id}}
    <br/>NAME: {{name}}
    <br/>E-MAIL: {{user_email}}
    <br/>
    <a ng-click="logout();">Logout</a>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if I am using `$rootScope.$on('$StateChangeStart', function(...)` correctly. Any suggestions?

Comment: "`but the session data is not stored or accessible in the $rootScope and I can not use it in my views`" in the sense? Are you talking about the user details?

Comment: have to check `$stateChangeStart` is working by `console.log(results)` inside it. I think it would be `results.data` . btw php tag is unnecessary.

Comment: Yeah, I believe that the problem resides with the $stateChangeStart. It wont log the returned object to the console. I don't think the event is ever fired. BTW, removed PHP based tags. Thanks

Comment: please check version of `angular-ui.router`. $state* events has been deprecated in latest version 1.0 alpha

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$stateChangeStart` - Note the first letter is small instead of caps

Comment: @Chinni - that was definitely one problem! lol, always something simple. Still can't get the user data to the view, but the results from the get request to the server are there in the .run(...)

Comment: Chinni - that was the only problem ... everything works as it should now. I f you want to answer the question, I'll accept your response as the answer - thanks

Comment: Thanks. I've added it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `$stateChangeStart`. Note the first letter is small and not caps.